# Regular expression to match string to an array

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to form a regex that will match a string that "looks" like an array.

- Must start with `[`, `{` or `(`
- Must end with `]`, `}`, or `)`
- Does not matter if start and end use same bracket (e.g. `(....}` is fine)
- Items are separated by commas
- All white-space types are ignored
- Empty arrays must be accepted

What I came up with initially was

```
'/\s*[\[|\{|\(]\s*\w+\s*[,\s*\w+]*\s*[\]|\}|\)]\s*/'
```

Unfortunately this doesn't accept an empty array.  So I tried another

```
'/\s*[\[|\{|\(][\s*\w+\s*]?[,\s*\w+]*\s*[\]|\}|\)]\s*/'`
```

This one allows the empty array but also allows an array that starts with a comma after the opening bracket (e.g. `[, item, item]`).

What I'm doing currently is using two different regexes and checking that one or the other matches.  The other regex is similar to the first one I mentioned here but only allows zero or more whitespace characters between the open and closing markers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used spaces and newlines below for clarity.  They should be removed or use a regex option that ignores them.  I find it easier to develop regexs this way.

```
[\[\{\(]
    \s*
    (
    |
        \w+\s*
        (,\s*\w+\s*)*
    )
[\]\}\)]
```

This has not been tested, but I hope it's very close.

Comment: For some reason I let the fact that parens capture sub-patterns blind me to the fact that they could be used to list alternatives.  Can square brackets be nested similarly or is that the reason for using parens instead?

Comment: @Matt in all regex systems that I am familiar with, [] are used only for ranges like [a-z0-9_].  They do not nest and do not group.  () are used for captures and to modify operator order just like in arithmetic (1+2)*3 vs 1+2*3. () can be nested.  The capturing part of a given pair of () can often be disabled, for example (?:expression) in perl.

Answer (score 1):

Try treating an empty array as a special case and or it with the populated array regex you have already. Something like (untested):

```
'(?:[\({[]\s*[\)}\]]|/\s*[\[|\{|\(]\s*\w+\s*[,\s*\w+]*\s*[\]|\}|\)]\s*)/'
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how this works.  Can you provide some more explanation?